# How to get selection of paragraphs in Angular 6?

Tags: angular, ecmascript-6

I am trying to get the start and end indices of a selection of text in my Angular application.

I am using `window.getSelection()` method to find my selection, and using the `focusOffset` property to get the start of the selection and to get the end of the selection I'm simply just adding the length of the selected string with the `focusOffset` property found.

**The problem here is, when I am selecting a particular snippet of text, its selecting anything in the entire document due to `(window.getSelection())`, but I only want to select the text.**

[image]

Is there some foolproof way to get the selection of text along with their start and end indices in that particular column of the table only.

Here's the [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rug1sm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) to the current part of the app, that I'm trying to make.

Answer (score 2):

Select string using following code and then manipulate:

```
window.getSelection().toString();
```